# How to read value of template / html / temporary declared Input variable

Tags: angular

I have a input field and declared a temporary variable for it.

```html
    <input
      type="text"
      #inputText
      autofocus
      placeholder="Add text"
    />

    <button>{{inputText.value.length > 0 ? 'Send' : 'Type'}}</button>
    <br/>
    Length = {{inputText.value.length}}
    <br/>
    Value = {{inputText.value}}
    <br/>
    Value Length = {{(inputText.target && inputText.target.value)}}
```

How can I achieve printing the value **without** using `[(ngModel)]`. Is there any other way to bind the value to `#inputText`

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lpki1y)

Comment: I tried with @ViewChild, is this what you are looking for ? type somthin in input button and click  [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txyfzk)

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyup method for this => (keyup)="changeInput(inputText.value)".

In your component.ts, inside changeInput method assign this to another var which you an use to display in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly don't you want to use NgModel?

```
<input [(ngModel)]="inputText" placeholder="Add Text" type="text" />
```

As an alternative you can use any of these https://angular.io/guide/user-input